# How difficult is to find relatives abroad?

Tags: relatives

How difficult can it be to find relatives in a diferent country? (e.g. I'm from Czech Republic and I am searching for relatives in another european country or US.)

Comment: Are you talking about living relatives?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History. The information you are seeking is certainly the sort of thing that this site can help with. But you will need to provide some more background to get best value. Begin by telling us when your relatives left and which countries they traveled to. Why did they leave (migration, displaced by war, ...?) What information do you already know (date and place of birth?) Good luck.

Comment: Luke: I was talking about living relatives but according to your comment we can speak about both living and dead relatives.

Comment: Saric, as others have suggested, this is a very broad question. It would be easier for you to get good quality answers if you provide move information about the locations involved and the time period). In particular, there will be very different answers when talking about the US and different European countries. I'd also suggest asking "How can I find..." rather than "How difficult is it to find..." as the answers will then be more useful to you and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more you know about them, the easier it will be. For instance, if you know 4 siblings, their ages, the town name, their spouses and children, then chances are good that you can find one or more. Then one leads to the next.

I received a tree from a distant cousin with some German relatives listed. It didn't take long to find a few of them using Facebook and the German Google site www.google.de

People ages 15 to 25 often have a Facebook account. Older people may be listed on business and career/resume sites. Younger people may be listed on a school soccer team, etc.

If you don't have exact names, you can find a historian or genealogist within the town by contacting the mayor's office or a local church.

I also check the public trees at Ancestry.com to see who is researching common ancestors. This has led to some foreign relatives.